# catalina.out rotation without tomcat restart

Tags: bash, logging, tomcat7

I am using tomcat 7 in centos. Catalina.out log file size is rapidly increasing. So i wish to rotate log file based on size or daily basics. Already i tried something using logrotate.conf.

```
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/logs/catalina.out {
  copytruncate
  missingok
  daily
  su root root
  size 20M
  create
  rotate 3
  compress
  notifempty
  dateext
    dateformat -web01-%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

Eventhough rotation is done.  without tomcat restart catalina.out log file is not writing. its still 0 KB.
Please give me any suggestion to complete this.

Comment: What user is the tomcat process running as?

Comment: centos 7 username as root.

Comment: Use `lsof -Pn catalina.out` to display the process which has opened the log file.